# Lsyncd did not create a lsyncd.pid file

Tags: linux, centos, rsync

I just installed lsyncd-2.1.5 on a CentOS 6.4 server.  I was able to run make and make install on the distribution to compile the daemon.  I was able to setup the following configure file at /etc/lsyncd.lua.  I was able to setup the daemon file at /etc/init.d/lsyncd.  I was also able to setup the logs correctly.  However, when I go to run start command on lsyncd, it throws the error:

```
       /bin/bash: line 1: Illegal Insruction /usr/local/bin/lsyncd -pidfile /var/run/lsyncd.pid /etc/lsyncd.lua
```

I checked at /var/run for the file lsyncd.pid and this file was not created by lsyncd.
Any thoughts on what I should do here?  Can I get this file created?  Do I have to reinstall?
Let me know if I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to solve this issue.  I removed all instances of my lsyncd distribution.  I had previously downloaded and compiled my package in the folder /var/tmp, so I now navigated to the root folder and ran my download command here.  I un-tarred the package, and compiled the package in the root folder and setup all of my configuration files.  After I started the service now, the lsyncd.pid file was now in the /var/run folder.  Very strange.  Can anyone tell me what the difference is between compiling in the root or /var/tmp?
Or is this possibly a situation where something possibly went wrong the first time around?  Does anyone have any insight on this?